# How do I pass arguments to my pl/python custom function

Tags: postgresql, plpython

I am trying to create my first ever custom function that uses arguments in pl/python. I have created triggers before using pl/python language but these kind of functions don't have arguments.
The code of the function I have created is below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION test_pl_pyton_func(table_name TEXT, field_name TEXT) RETURNS TEXT AS
    $BODY$
    plan = plpy.prepare("SELECT DISTINCT $1 FROM $2", ['TEXT', 'TEXT'])
    result = plpy.execute(plan, [field_name, table_name])
    while i < result.nrows():
        print(result[i][field_name])
        i = i+1
    $BODY$
    LANGUAGE plpython3u;
```

Now if I run:

```
SELECT test_pl_pyton_func(table_name, field_name);
```

I get the following error:

```
spiexceptions.SyntaxError: syntax error at or near "$2"
    LINE 1: SELECT DISTINCT $1 FROM $2
                                    ^
        QUERY:  SELECT DISTINCT $1 FROM $2
        CONTEXT:  Traceback (most recent call last):
          PL/Python function "test_pl_pyton_func", line 2, in <module>
            plan = plpy.prepare("SELECT DISTINCT $1 FROM $2", ['TEXT', 'TEXT'])
        PL/Python function "test_pl_pyton_func"
```

What am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot put neither table name nor field names as prepared statement's arguments. The table names and the queried columns must always be constant in a prepared query. If they weren't, the DBMS wouldn't know the return types for the query, so it wouldn't be able to `prepare` the query.

For your use case you can use simple python formatting combined with `plpy`'s quoting (escaping):

```
plpy.prepare(f"SELECT DISTINCT {plpy.quote_ident(field_name)} FROM {plpy.quote_ident(table_name)}")
```

More on the escaping functions here: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpython-util.html (see: `plpy.quote_literal`, `plpy.quote_ident`, `plpy.quote_nullable`).